# Export wordpress image ID based off keyword search

Tags: images, export

I would like to know how to go about exporting a load of image ID's based off the image name. For example

'how to dig gold' search may have a load of images like

```
how to dig gold.mp4001.jpg
how to dig gold.mp4002.jpg
how to dig gold.mp4003.jpg
how to dig gold.mp4004.jpg
how to dig gold.mp4005.jpg
```

Their wordpress image IDs are along the range of 8322-8326. I would like to run a single command to do this if possible as I will be doing this for hundreds of different keywords. The results should look like the following

```
how to dig gold-8322
how to dig gold-8323
how to dig gold-8324
how to dig gold-8325
how to dig gold-8326
```

Comment: can you explain your problem lil bit more? this makes no sense to me

Comment: There are a load of images called how to dig gold.mp$$$$.jpg I need to run a command that searches for this keyword 'how to dig gold' and exports all the attachment IDs for images in our media that contain that exact search term.